# mySQL delete duplicate but preserve specific id

Tags: mysql

I have a table with **id**, **articleID** and **categoryID**.
One articleID can have multiple categoryID.

Now i want to delete every entry with **categoryID = 3049** if there is also another entry for the same **articleID** with a **categoryID**

So i made this query, but it gibes me the error:

> #1093 - Table 's_articles_categories' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data

```
   DELETE FROM s_articles_categories
    WHERE categoryID = 3049 AND articleID IN
        (
        SELECT articleID
        FROM s_articles_categories
        WHERE articleID IN
            (
            SELECT articleID
            FROM s_articles_categories
            GROUP BY articleID
            HAVING count(articleID) > 1
            )
        AND categoryID != 3049
        )
```

How can i change this query?

I also tried this, but it gives me the same error

```
DELETE FROM s_articles_categories as t1
WHERE id in (SELECT t1.id FROM `s_articles_categories` as t1
JOIN `s_articles_categories` AS t2 on t1.articleID = t2.articleID
WHERE t1.categoryID = 3049 and t2.categoryID != 3049)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the "specified twice" error on DELETE, wrap your inner query up in an additional "anonymous" inner query (named x here):

```
DELETE t.* 
FROM   `s_articles_categories` t
WHERE  `categoryID` = 3049 
  AND  `articleID` IN (
    SELECT `articleID`
    FROM (
      SELECT `articleID` 
      FROM   `s_articles_categories` 
      WHERE  `categoryID` != 3049)
    x)
```

Comment: Thank you, but that seems not to work. This gives me a syntax error on t1